# I am getting "NaN" to the text box after calculation

Tags: javascript

```
case 0:                        
    var val = $('#Monday total').val();                       
    add = parse Int($('#effort_'+record id+'_'+i).val())+parse Int(val);
    $('#Monday total').val(add);
break;
```

I am getting NaN to the text box after calculation.

Comment: [`ID` attributes should not have space in between](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Comment: try using `Number()`

Answer (score 2):

Not `parse Int` its `parseInt`

Use,

```
add = parseInt($('#effort_'+record_id+'_'+i).val())+parseInt(val);
```

**Edit**

In addition, you should use the radix parameter to ensure decimal conversion

i.e. `add = parseInt($('#effort_'+record_id+'_'+i).val(),10)+parseInt(val,10);`

If you are using monetary values then you should be using `parseFloat()`

Comment: In addtion, you should use the radix parameter to ensure decimal conversion i.e. add = parseInt($('#effort_'+record id+'_'+i).val(),10)+parseInt(val,10);. If you are using monetary values then you should be using parseFloat()

Comment: this one is still showing "NaN" add = parseInt($('#effort_'+recordid+'_'+i).val(),10)+parseInt(val,10);

Comment: @venkat check the value of first parameter by, console(parseInt($('#effort_'+recordid+'_'+i).val(),10)); Check its a number